# How to populate data in an input form element with date type in given format ASP. NET and ANGULAR

Tags: asp.net, json, angular, input

I am trying to populate data but I couldn't fix date parts as given on picture with red underlines, I need them to be like choosen format 'MM-DD-YYYY'. I am able bring jobName and jobType but I need start and end dates as well

[image]

Here is my table;

```
[Key]
public int JobId { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
public string JobName { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime JobEndDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public int JobType { get; set; }
```

Here is my service;

```
getToDoJobsList() {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseURI + '/ToDoJobs');
}
```

Here is my ts with how I post and get jobs;

```
export class ToDoJobComponent implements OnInit {

  toDoJobsForms: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  toDoTypesArray = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private toDoTypes: ToDoTypeService,
              private toDoJobsService: ToDoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.toDoTypes.getToDoJobTypes()
      .subscribe(res => this.toDoTypesArray = res as []);



    //get the list of to do jobs
    this.toDoJobsService.getToDoJobsList().subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res == []) {
          this.addToDoJobForms();
        }
        else { 
          (res as [] ).forEach((toDoJobs: any) => {
            this.toDoJobsForms.push(this.fb.group({
              jobId: [toDoJobs.jobId],
              jobName: [toDoJobs.jobName, Validators.required],
              jobStartDate: toDoJobs.jobStartDate = moment(toDoJobs.jobStartDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
              jobEndDate: [toDoJobs.jobEndDate = moment(toDoJobs.jobEndDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'), Validators.required],
              jobType: [toDoJobs.jobType, Validators.required]
            })

            );
          })
        }
      }
    )
  }

  addToDoJobForms() {
    this.toDoJobsForms.push(this.fb.group({
      jobId: 0,
      jobName: '',
      jobStartDate: 0,
      jobEndDate: 0,
      jobType: 0
    }));
  }

  //post new record
  recordSubmit(fg: FormGroup) {
    this.toDoJobsService.postToDoJob(fg.value)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          fg.patchValue({ jobId: res.jobId });
        }
      );
  }
```

My html;

```
<form class="tr" [formGroup]="fg" *ngFor="let fg of toDoJobsForms.controls" (submit)="recordSubmit(fg)">
      <div class="td">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="jobStartDate" />
      </div>
</form>
```

And finally the JSON;
[image]

Comment: change format to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Dude you saved my day! Thanks man! Yeah that solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome :)